# Empty app icon on iPad for iPhone only application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store

I have an iPhone application which is not optimised to work on iPad, but it contains all the icons for iPad. When I install an app on iPad - there is no icon. Also, when I download my app from the store on iPad - it doesn't have an icon...

In Xcode 9 I've marked the app as "universal" and built it. The icon appeared! Marked back as "iPhone only" - icon disappeared.

So the question is: How to make an "iPhone only" app has an icon on iPad?

**P.S.**

Created a new icon set with iPad support. Icons provided and activated. Doesn't help

**P.S.**

Cleaning and deleting derived data doesn't help

**P.S.**

I have an icon for iPad and **iPad all checkmark** is selected in project.

**I've found the reason:**

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict/>
<key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
<dict/>
```

These lines in `info.plist` made the icon set disabled. And I have no idea where they came from... When I removed these lines - the icon appeared on iPad.

**Thanks for help!!!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These lines in **info.plist** made the iPad icon in assets to be ignored

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict/>
<key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
<dict/>
```

When I removed these lines - the icon appeared on iPad

Comment: Did this violate Apple's review policy anyway? Have your app got approved?

Comment: @ramgandhi It doesn't violate any policy. These keys accidentally appear in some circumstances and it's okay to remove them if required.

Answer (score 1):

just navigate to the attributes inspector ,and select the check box.
[image]

Comment: The app contains all the icons for iPad and they are activated with checkmark

Comment: can you make a screen shot?

Comment: I have attached screenshots to my original question

Comment: try cleaning and deleting derived data. it may be a bug of xcode

Comment: I have figured out the problem. Thanks for help!